# How to count elements by class and use loop to display items dynamically in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to build a slider editor where the slides appearing in the website, can be changed or removed. I'm trying to push all the contents of slider in a popup where the contents can be editable. The problem I'm facing is I've sliders into div with class name like this:

**Main Content:**

```
<div class="carousel-inner" id="nitsslider">
            <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(../nits-img/global/templates/himu/slider/slide3.jpg)">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="heading animated bounceInDown">'Himu' Onepage HTML Template</h2>
                        <p class="animated bounceInUp">Fully Professional one page template</p>
                        <a class="btn btn-default slider-btn animated fadeIn" href="#">Get Started</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="background-image: url(../nits-img/global/templates/himu/slider/slide2.jpg)">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="heading animated bounceInDown">Get All in Onepage</h2>
                        <p class="animated bounceInUp">Everything is outstanding </p> <a class="btn btn-default slider-btn animated fadeIn" href="#">Get Started</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="background-image: url(../nits-img/global/templates/himu/slider/slide1.jpg)">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="heading animated bounceInRight">Fully Responsive Template</h2>
                        <p class="animated bounceInLeft">100% Responsive HTML template</p>
                        <a class="btn btn-default slider-btn animated bounceInUp" href="#">Get Started</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to append the contents like heading, paragraph and button content to a box where it can be edited.

Shall I use `each function` element by taking `class="item"` I mean I want to append the content in following format:

**Dynamic Content:**

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_15_1">
<div class="portlet-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="caption uplimg">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Change slide content
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-body">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Change Image</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="tiles">
                    <div class="tile image selected">
                        <div class="tile-body">
                            <img src="../../assets/admin/pages/media/gallery/image2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="tile-object">
                            <div class="name">
                                Media
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Heading</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="25" name="defaultconfig" id="maxlength_defaultconfig">
                    <span class="help-block">
  Enter Slider heading. Maxlength is 25 chars.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Content</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="25" name="defaultconfig" id="maxlength_defaultconfig">
                    <span class="help-block">
  Enter Slider content. Maxlength is 25 chars.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Button text</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="25" name="defaultconfig" id="maxlength_defaultconfig">
                    <span class="help-block">
  Enter button text. Maxlength is 25 chars.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where input box has the values of the main content.

Comment: Use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) or [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) as best suit your needs... if you need to do it to every element with a especific class, then use `$(".yourClass").append(...);` or `$("yourDOM_obj").appendTo($(".yourClass"));` check what works for you.

Comment: Count elements by class: `$("YourClass").length`, loop you could use the old `for(i=0; i<$("YourClass").length; i++){ $("YourClass")[i]...; }` or the jQuery way `$("YourClass").each(function(){ __your code__ });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to put the values in array and executed the each statement to append the values. Following is the code I used:

```
$('#nitsslider > .item').each(function (i) {
    var sliderimage = [];
    var sliderheading = [];
    var sliderpara = [];
    var sliderbutton = [];
    sliderimage[i] = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1');
    sliderheading[i] = $(this).find('h2').text();
    sliderpara[i] = $(this).find('p').text();
    sliderbutton[i] = $(this).find('a').text();

 and append the dynamic content....

});
```